# Get name of a variable as input and change the variable with that name

Tags: bash

I get the name of a variable from the script user as the first argument and I echo the value of said variable back to the console:

```
#!/bin/bash
variablename=$1
echo "The value of $variablename is: " ${!variablename}
```

This works great!

What I can't get to work is if I want to change that variable into the value of the second argument from the user. An example with a syntax error is:

```
#!/bin/bash
variablename=$1
echo "The value of $variablename is: " ${!variablename}
echo "I will now try to change the value into $2."
(!variablename}=$2
# The above line generates: {!variablename}=2: command not found
```

In other words: If it is possible, how do I get a variable *name* from the user and both read (already solved) and write to said variable?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had a flash all of a sudden, minutes after asking for help, and I think I have a solution:

```
#!/bin/bash
variablename=$1
echo "The value of $variablename is: " ${!variablename}
echo "I will now try to change the value into $2."
eval "$variablename=$2"
echo "Success! $variablename now has the value ${!variablename}!"
```

It works. Is there a better way?

Comment: No, eval is the correct way to go.  You might need to worry about blanks in $2, though - and single quotes and double quotes and backslashes.

Comment: Thanks for asserting me I'm on the right way. I'll do some parameter validation if I create something of any re-usability value. At the moment I'm mostly messing around trying to understand Bash more in-depth. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Your solution will work but the variable will only have that value within your script.  It won't affect the "calling" application's variable.

When you run a script or program it spawns a new shell with a copy of the environment.  This is by design so your script doesn't modify things like `PATH`.

If you want your script to be able to modify environment variables for the calling shell you need to either `source scriptname` or `. scriptname`.  This is how .bashrc works.

Comment: Thanks for the additional information! "source scriptname" worked fine for this. Could you elaborate a bit on ".scriptname" as I didn't understand that approach?

Comment: source scriptname   is essentially the same, but it's bash specific using the dot instead of source is posix compatible

Comment: The syntax is ". scriptname", not ".scriptname". The dot command is synonymous with the source command.

Comment: libt: Ah! tnek.knowledge++
converter42: Thanks for fixing that syntax error!